# Gridview check constraints before editing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and I want to check some constraints before editing a row. More specifically, if the user is is the author of the post he is able to edit the row.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
            AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" 
            DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" 
            GridLines="None">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                            CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                            CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                            CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                            CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="topicID" HeaderText="topicID" 
                    SortExpression="topicID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="author" HeaderText="author" 
                    SortExpression="author" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="date" SortExpression="date" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="content" SortExpression="content">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("content") %>' class="com"></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("content") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

I am thinking to add onclick() and remove CommandName from the ItemTemplate, but I dont see how I could launch the Edit in my validate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are thinking right. add onClick() and check

```
protected void IBNew_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_User.HasPermission("IMS", "T00-0001", PermissionTypes.Create))
        {
            js.ShowUPAlert(this, "Permission denied – Please contact your administrator");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("EditCategory.aspx");
        }

    }
```

You can write your own logic to check permission.

You can also use `RowDataBound` event to find edit button and enable/disable it after permission check.

```
protected void gvShow_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
          LinkButton lnkEdit= e.Row.FindControl("lnkEdit") as LinkButton;
          if(//your condition)
          {
             lnkEdit.Enable=true\false;
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice trick to solve my problem. The Redirect should be included in the if statement in my case considering that I edit my answer on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Other solution is to set Enabled atribute to `Edit` Button.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonIEDEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"
                                Enabled='<%# setEdit(Convert.ToString(Eval("author"))) %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

Backgroud code:

```
protected bool setEdit(string author)
{
    //check cond
}
```